# Lucene.net visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net, lucene.net

I want to create a simple Visual Basic.NET solution using LUCENE.NET, indexing files in a folder.
I have searched all day, but the example code that I find is in C#.
Can someone please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I had a better answer for you but I suspect the best approach is to use a C# to VB.Net code conversion tool.  Like you, I have never seen a VB code example for using Lucene.Net.  With one of these tools, you can paste the C# code into a text box, hit the convert button and it will display the theoretically equivalent VB.Net code.

Here are a couple code converters that may be useful for you:

1. https://converter.telerik.com/
2. https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/
3. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.CodeConverter